# Get $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ element of sorted subset sums

Tags: algorithms, knapsack-problems, subset-sum

I have a sorted multiset (size < 100, real valued) and want to determine the $n^{\mathrm{th}}$ largest of all possible subset sums (including multiplicity in the sums).

Attempt at solving :

I have been looking at ordering the sums starting with the unbounded knapsack problem (UKP) with equal weights to find the sets of each size with minimal sum, then establishing a rule for determining the order of corresponding sets after replacing elements, in the hope that this would reduce the number of comparisons. However, this doesn't seem to simplify the problem.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/89419/algorithm-wanted-enumerate-all-subsets-of-a-set-in-order-of-increasing-sums

Comment: Thank you for that reference. It does accomplish what I'm looking for, but I can't reach large values in the search space with that speed. Is there any chance I could skip over a chunk of subsets without explicitly finding and summing them?

Comment: The problem is NP-hard: if we could solve your problem efficiently, it would be easy to solve the subset sum problem too (using binary search).  I don't know whether there is a way to take advantage of the known algorithms for subset sum to solve this for the a multiset of size 100; I haven't figured out a way, but maybe someone else will have some ideas.

Comment: I see, you have clarified the relation between my problem and subset sum and a lower bound on time complexity is already very good to know, thank you.